# Updating Hash Key and Value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

Here is the sample code:

```
books = {
  Steve_Jobs: 10,
  Haryy_Potter: 7
}
```

I want to update a key and its value of this hash.

1. I don't know how I can change `Harry_Potter` to `Bill_Gates`.
2. For the value, I can try this:

   ```
   books[:Harry_Potter] = 10
   ```

I tried `books.update[:Harry_Potter] = "Bill_Gates".to_sym`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If something "doesn't work", please explain ***how*** it doesn't work. Do you get error messages? What output are you currently getting?

Comment: What do you mean by changing `Harry_Potter` to something? Where is it?

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, I'll keep it in mind next time but you should not vote down my question just because I made a mistake. I'm human not a bot!

Comment: Hi @Abhi, please don't assume that the people who comment on your posts are the same people who downvote them, because I did not downvote this! :(

Comment: @Cupcake I'm so sorry! I'm new to Stackoverflow and English is my second language :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
books[:Bill_Gates] = books.delete(:Harry_Potter)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
change = { "Harry_Potter" => "Bill_Gates" }
books = Hash[ books.map { |k, v| [change[k] || k, v] } ]
```

Put the keys you want to change and the values you want to change them to in the change hash.